# CQ5 - Widget for displaying sample HTML

Tags: aem

I am trying to build a widget that has an area that will display sample of ~20 line HTML code. This sample code must be selectable so the user will be able to copy + paste it into their own text editor.

Currently I am using an xtype `displayfield` and using the `fieldDescription` to put my HTML code inside. I realized though that this `fieldDescription` does not allow me to format my code. I also tried using an xtype `textarea` and setting the `emptyText` as my HTML code, but clicking in the textarea would remove the HTML code.

The user story for this is that I have a textarea where the user will be populating a textarea with HTML code. This HTML code must be structured in a certain way so the CSS will format their code correctly. I want to include an example of how this HTML code should be structured.

EDIT - It will be great if I can apply the font-face Courier to this for ease of readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Try using `value` property of `textarea`.
- Set `ignoreData` to true to avoid the value being populated from content.
- To make sure it doesn't get saved back as a property - leave `name` empty, or just set a value that doesn't start with `./`
- To achieve different font face - play with CSS on a page. If you want to add specific CSS class to your widget, use `overCls` property.
- Find more [on the documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.TextArea)

Comment: I've tried setting a field's name to something not prefixed with "./".  At least with 5.6.1, the field's value did get saved to the absolute or relative location specified.  It did not, however, get loaded when the dialog opened.  Just a gotcha to watch for.